# Bluetooth le modify iBeacon's UUID, minor and major

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am searching for the API docs related to modification of iBeacon's UUID, Minor and Major through an Android application.

Please help me on this, I have searched and found that it is nearly possible but it is like a workaround and there are no example or code for android.

In short I want to re-configure my iBeacon.

Comment: Which iBeacon hardware are you using?

Comment: I am using Blue Beacon.

Comment: You will need to contact them for details - there is no standard way to modify the major and minor - it is beacon specific.  A quick google didn't turn any thing up for Blue Beacon - their Alibaba listing mentions a data sheet but I couldn't see anything at RFODM.COM